# getting Black Screen while integrating CoreData to my ToDo app Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I am learning Swift from Online Course and while my instructor integrating CoreData to her existing code, She creates a new core data model and copy-paste App Delegate. But in her DataModel, there is not a SceneDelegate while there is in mine.

The problem is that I can not do the same things as her because of these differences. Therefore, I copied SceneDelegate.swift file into my Xcode project and copy other things from DataModel App Delegate.

After this solution, I got a black screen.

I do not know I should add her and my app delegate or not but differences are while I do not have applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackgraound, etc. in the Core Data Model App Delegate, she does have.

How can I integrate CoreData into my project while there are these differences?

Thanks!

this is my app delegate file

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `AppDelegate` code here?

Comment: i have just updated, btw i solved the problem by copying app delegate from my instructor's app delegate file but still i want to learn how i can solve this problem in my future projects

Comment: @AliErenAK I ran into something similar but in a slightly different context. I put a detailed answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60421107/setting-up-coredata-with-scenedelegate-unknown-identifier-window-error-ios/60421108#60421108

Comment: This may fix this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453661/1890317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these lines of code:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCoreData")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Put it after the `applicationWillTerminate` function but within the AppDelegate class.

The code is automatically added when creating an Xcode project and checking the 'Use Core Data' checkbox. You can always create a new Xcode project, check the 'Use Core Data' checkbox and then copy and paste the code near the end of the AppDelegate which was automatically created.