# Setting Up CoreData with SceneDelegate - unknown identifier 'window' error - iOS 13 onwards

Tags: core-data, ios13, appdelegate, uiwindow, uiscenedelegate

I was trying to use the official apple documentation for Core Data. Found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack). I also ran into a question which was related to my issue, right here on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128296/getting-black-screen-while-integrating-coredata-to-my-todo-app-swift).

I ran into an issue where, it kept saying that 'window' is not available in the context of AppDelegate. This is the very basic step as per the official documentation.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
    if let rootVC = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
        rootVC.container = persistentContainer
    }        
    return true
}
```

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue boils down to the changes, primarily, support for multiple scenes in iOS 13 and above. check this [reddit link for the discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/hackingwithswift/comments/cdfbcd/project_7_missing_window_variable_in_appdelegate/).

The solution is to move some of things from AppDelegate to SceneDelegate.

Here is the final form of the essential parts of the above two classes.

----SceneDelegate

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController else {
        print("ViewController not found")
        return
    }
    //set the storage here
    rootVC.container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer
    //I dont want a  UI navigation controller.
    //let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
    //self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
    //I want to use my basic view controller here. use rootNC to get a UI navigation controller
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

--AppDelegate (remains unchanged )

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //before iOS 13 you would be putting stuff here but not anymore.
    return true
}
```

Finally, you will leave the storage related code, where it was, in AppDelegate itself.